# How do I check if an anonymous object properties are not empty C#

Tags: c#, xml, anonymous-types

I have a WebApi which has some action methods that accepts an XMLDocument value. Inside these functions I converted that XML to `AnonymousObject`, then, I do my logic.

Now, I got the XML with empty attributes, and I need to do a check which can check all properties in that anonymous object if which are null or empty, I did something there but it didn't work, although, I passed an XML with empty attributes.

```
<Students>
    <Student ID="" Name="" />
    <Student ID="" Name="" />
</Students>
```

This was an example of XML inputs which I got, and there are some other forms for the same, so, I wrote a function that checks if the attributes are empty or not after deserializing the XML to an anonymous object as follows:

```
//This handles the conversion from XML to the anonymous object

XDocument doc;
using (var sr = new StringReader(request.InnerXml))
{
    doc = XDocument.Load(sr);
}

var clientList = doc.Descendants()
    .Where(d => string.Equals(d.Name.LocalName, "Student", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .Select(
        d =>
            new
            {
                studentId = d.Attributes().SingleOrDefault(a =>
                        string.Equals(a.Name.LocalName, "ID", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    ?.Value,
                studentName = d.Attributes().SingleOrDefault(a =>
                        string.Equals(a.Name.LocalName, "Name", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    ?.Value
            }).ToList();
```

Then I wrote that function which should validate that anonymous object's properties, all should have a value, but if I passed the above XML, it will return **FALSE** as if there is no property with empty value:

```
public static bool IsAnyNullOrEmpty(object objectToBeChecked)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in objectToBeChecked.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (pi.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                string value = (string)pi.GetValue(objectToBeChecked);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
        //return objectToBeChecked.GetType().GetProperties()
        //    .Where(pi => pi.GetValue(objectToBeChecked) is string)
        //    .Select(pi => (string) pi.GetValue(objectToBeChecked))
        //    .Any(string.IsNullOrEmpty);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Any advice?

### EDIT #1

While debugging I noticed that:

- Property Name: `` <>f__AnonymousType3`1 ``
- Property Type: `` Name = "<>f__AnonymousType3`1" FullName = "<>f__AnonymousType3`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]" ``

Comment: Have you used the debugger?

Comment: Why don´t you just create a class? Although you *could* provide an instance of an anoymous type into a method, there´s no real point on doing so. In particula when deserializing a file you have some string knowledge about what the objects in that file look like. Hiding this information is a bad idea.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, this api controller has bout 30 action methods, and all of these methods receive different XML format, this means that I will have about 30 mapping classes for the incoming XML inputs, which is like a headache for me, so, I chose the anonymous objects instead

Comment: I can´t see where this produces any headache. Instead you get problems when trying to read those anonymous objects, as you´ve allready noticed. I suppose you want to work with those objects in some kind afterwards, so you have not only to validate them, but also to read their properties afterwards where you´d loop the properties again and again. If you had the types at the first place you directly know what members an object exposes.

Comment: Let me continue a little further. After you validated your objects, what are you doing then?

Comment: Look ... the scenario here, I got XML data from a third-party, and I should validate this data before doing any process at my end. On the other hand, that party will provide me with fixed 30 XML schema, which means I should have a mapping model for each one here and I wanna avoid that as much as I can, then I went to the anonymous objects, and I discovered later that I should check all properties values as there is a robot on party's side sends the data, so, I decided to have one generic method to pass the object to it, and it checks all entire properties of that object ... to be continued (1)

Comment: to be continued (2) >> then if i got any property empty or null, I should stop and reply back to that party that I couldn't process his request ... etc.

Comment: If you even have an xml-schema-definition (some xsd), it´s easy to extract the classes needed to de-serialize the objects using xsd.exe. This will create all the classes for you together with the serialization-information.

Comment: Nope, what I have is something like I shared .. the third party just shared some XML as I shared above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it like that:

```
public static bool IsAnyNullOrEmpty(object objectToBeChecked, params string[] parametersToBeChecked)
{
    foreach (var obj in (IEnumerable)objectToBeChecked)
    {
        foreach (var pi in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (parametersToBeChecked.Contains(pi.Name))
            {
                var value = (string)pi.GetValue(obj);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

This will take the object (anonymous object) and properties names which you want to check, this works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest to use a named class instead of an anonymous one for that. Obviously you have some strong knowledge on what properties the instances in the xml expose, so there´s no use on hiding this knowledge away.

Imagine some day you don´t want only string-properties but also numbers. Then you´d have to re-invent great parts ofyour logic, not only the validation but only the actual *work* with the objects.

I suppose you want to do more than just validating your objects. You surely want to *do* something with them. In order to do so you need to know what members they expose. In your current implementation they´re just `objects`, which don´t expose much to their clients. So in order to do anything you´d need something like this:

```
var a = ((theType) myInstance).StudentName;
```

But you´ve lost all information about what `theType` actually is, so all you can do with the object is calling `ToString`, `Equals` and some other members derived from `object`.

In your special case you allready know that the instance in your xml has a `StudentName`- and a `studentId`-property. So why should you throw that away and do as if you didn´t know that?

As of [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types):

> To pass an anonymous type, or a collection that contains anonymous types, as an argument to a method, you can declare the parameter as type object. However, doing this defeats the purpose of strong typing. If you must
>   store query results or pass them outside the method boundary, consider
>   using an ordinary named struct or class instead of an anonymous type.

Comment: Thank you ... your answer was inspired for me, it helped me to find out a solution for my issue.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a concrete class implementation if you want to pass your object in some method.
Copy your xml structur and let Visual Studio create a deserialization class for you.
Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste Xml as Class

If you know your Xml-Structur, why you want to loose that information.

Comment: I just have about 30 XML structure here, which means I will get about 30 model, and I just wanna avoid that